# AWS CDK methodOptions wildcard syntax - is my intuition correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I've looked for docs that explain this but I've drawn a blank so far. You may specify methodOptions within deployOptions for a RestApi using a wildcard `/*/*`. My intuition is that if I also add specific HTTP verbs they will override whatever is set by the wildcard e.g.

```
methodOptions: {
    '/*/*': {
        throttlingBurstLimit: 30,
        throttlingRateLimit: 1
    },
    '/MyStack/POST': {
        throttlingBurstLimit: 1,
        throttlingRateLimit: 1
    },
    '/MyStack/PUT': {
        throttlingBurstLimit: 1,
        throttlingRateLimit: 1
    },
}
```

Is that actually the case, and either way, where might I find the docs that specify that?